# Numerical integration of the syms type in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I am using a generating function of Legendre polynomials (no matter what math entity it is) and for that I need to use "syms" type and then take the derivative by "diff" function.

```
function p=Plm(l,m)
syms x    
p = diff((x^2-1)^l,m);
end
```

Then the output of this function, "p", should be used to take a definite integral as

```
fun = @(x) Plm(l,m).*cos(x).^2
integral(fun,-1,1)
```

where "l" and "m" could be replaced by any positive integer. Matlab gives the error that it cannot integrate over symbolic x that comes from "p". What is the way to get around this?

Comment: I am sure, this is because `p` is of type `sym`. Also, you differentiate `p` with respect to `m` that gives `0` because, `p` is not function of `m`.

Comment: what is `l`? please post complete examples.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, I made changes to the code.

Comment: @AminR. brainkx is rigth. `p` is not dependant of m, thus it should be zero (it is, if you try)

Comment: Also `fun` makes no sense, its wrongly defined.

Comment: diff(fun,m) means the m'th derivative of fun and see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html for the integration process.

Comment: I simplified the math of code to make my point clear and simpler.

Comment: Try `int`. Or just wrap `Plm` with `double`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your definition of `fun`, as it doesn't return a numerical output. then you have a symbolic variable `x` and a numeric substitution of `x` (not the same) in the anonymous function. This makes things complicated, as the symbolic output of `Plm` returns a function that depends on a symbol that is not defined anymore, as it was created in the function workspace. This is a very bad programming practice, as in general, you wont be able to mix it with more symbolic `x` outside the function declaration

My suggestions would be either

1. include the `cos` inside `Plm`
2. Define `Plm` to accept a symbol defined outside the function scope, `function p=Plm(l,m,x)` being `x` the said symbol.

Else the following will work. The anonymous function must return a numerical value, so you should add the function `subs` and `double` to it as:

```
fun = @(xin)double(subs(Plm(l,m).*cos(x).^2,'x',xin))
```

The problem here is that the `x` in `cos(x)` is not a symbol, and if you substitute it by `xin` it will behave weirdly due to the behaviour of `subs`. However, we could hack the thing a bit, making  a symbolic `cos()` using the variable that `Plm` depends on, by using `symbar`. This will force the anonymous function to evaluate `Plm` twice (which is not good).

In short, this works :

```
fun = @(xin)double(subs(Plm(l,m).*cos(symvar(Plm(l,m))).^2,xin));
integral(fun,-1,1);
```